# Store java.util.Calendar field into one column

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus, jdoql

How to store java.util.Calendar field into one column with Datanucleus JDO. By default it is stored into two columns (millisecs, Timezone) with following JDO metadata.

```
field name="startDate" serialized="true" embedded="true" 
                                   persistence-modifier="persistent"
```

What need to be changed in metadata to store it into single column (Timestamp)?

Is it posible query (JDOQL) on calendar field when it is in two clumn?

Answer (score 0):

Store it in 1 column and potentially lose the timezone, want that ?
Metadata extension "calendar-one-column" set to "true" stores as 1 column (timestamp).

Comment: <field name="startDate" calendar-one-column="true"   persistence-modifier="persistent"/> 

Thanks, but this one is not working, Can you find any mistake on my metadata?

Comment: Where in the JDO spec or in the DTD/XSD for package.jdo do you find that syntax? I said "extension".